# drf error, 'Expected a dictionary, but got QuerySet.'

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with drf function view, I am getting an serializer error like this:
**{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got QuerySet.', code='invalid')]}**
Here's my function based view:

```
@api_view(["GET","POST"])
def UserSearch(request):
    selected_users = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=selected_users)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('user','name','surname','gender','country','city','sport')
        model = Profile
```

And Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)

    #date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.surname} from {self.city}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is here:

```py
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=selected_users)
```

this must be

```py
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(selected_users, many=True)
```

`data=` should not be present here, data is only for python dict, when you want to serialize a python dict for example.

why `many=True`, because you are querying more than 1 table rows, so it needs to be many

and your final code will be:

```py
@api_view(["GET","POST"])
def UserSearch(request):
    selected_users = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(selected_users, many=True) # <------
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(data=serializer.data)

    # that else was redundant
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: when i changed it, i got another error : {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet".', code='not_a_list')]}

Comment: and selected users look like this: <QuerySet [<Profile:   from >, <Profile: testnam testsur from testCity>, <Profile: test2 test2nsy from Rypin>, <Profile:   from >, <Profile: test4 TESTI from testCity>, <Profile: test 6 sixo from Bralin>]>

Comment: yes. remove the `data=`. check the answer, i've updated it.

Comment: now its going to work.

Comment: another error after this one: AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Comment: why are you validating with `is_valid()` ? what criteria you want the items to match ?

Comment: I thought it was required to response with data

Comment: nvm i just deleted is_valid segment and it works now, thanks a lot

Comment: if you want to validate the data you must create a custom function called `validate(self)` inside the serializer class and you need your custom condition. after that you are on your own.